# Анимированная смена блоков div по клику на них

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Разрабатываю страницу-информационное введение, на ней 5 блоков div (пока), каждый размером в окно браузера. Необходимо, чтобы при клику по 1-му блоку плавно отображался 2-й (одновременно с этим первый блок должен плавно исчезать), и так далее до конечного блока; fadeOut/fadeIn вполне устроит (можно и другие анимации, если не трудно). Пробовал через абсолютное позиционирование, visibility:hidden (или display:none) и jquery-смену атрибутов для каждого отдельного блока, но слишком громоздко.
Если решением является цикл, он должен быть конечным, т.к. последний div содержит ссылки на ветки сайта.

Comment: Если добавите ваш код, с которым что-то не получилось (не весь код вашего сайта, а именно тот кусок о котором спрашиваете), то скорее всего, кто-то поможет. А с такой постановкой... скорее заминусят.

Comment: В том то и дело, что мой код работает, но он довольно громоздок. А я ищу оптимальное решение проблемы.

Comment: в том то и дело, что нам нужен ваш код, что бы его улучшить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим css свойство `transition`.
Собственно, тут сложность заключается в том что бы понять работу [transition](http://htmlbook.ru/css/transition-timing-function)

У transition есть значение `transition-timing-function`

> transition-timing-function представляет собой математическую функцию,
> показывающую, как быстро по времени меняется указанное через
> transition-property значение свойства.

Это значит изменение какого-то свойства по времени будет одинаково, а вот анимация будет выглядеть по разному.

Пример:

```js
var pages = ['#page_1', '#page_2',  '#page_3', '#page_4',  '#page_5']; 
var allPages = '.page-container';

function show(prev, next) {
  $(prev).removeClass('show');
  $(next).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.page-container {
   transition: opacity 1s, width 1s step-end, height 1s step-end; 
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

.show {
   transition: opacity 3s linear; 
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   opacity: 1;
}

.page-container.one {
  background: green;
}
.page-container.two {
  background: red;
}
.page-container.three {
  background: yellow;
}
.page-container.four {
  background: olive;
}
.page-container.five {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_1" class="page-container one show" onClick="show(pages[0], pages[1])">1</div>
<div id="page_2" class="page-container two" onClick="show(pages[1], pages[2])">2</div>
<div id="page_3" class="page-container three" onClick="show(pages[2], pages[3])">3</div>
<div id="page_4" class="page-container four" onClick="show(pages[3], pages[4])">4</div>
<div id="page_5" class="page-container five" onClick="show(pages[4], pages[0])">5</div>
```

В этом примере смотрим на **закрытие** блока путем удаление класса `show`

```
.page-container {
       transition: opacity 1s, width 1s step-end, height 1s step-end; 
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       opacity: 0;
    }
```

Здесь сначала отработает  плавно `opacity: 0;`, а потом в конце периода схлопнутся `width` и `height`. Такой эффект достгается свойствами step-end и ease

*opacity 1s (по умолчанию ease)*

> **ease** Анимация начинается медленно, затем ускоряется и к концу движения
> опять замедляется
> **step-end** Как таковой анимации нет. Стилевые свойства находятся в
> начальном значении заданное время, затем сразу же принимают конечное
> значение.

В другом примере

```js
var pages = ['#page_1', '#page_2',  '#page_3', '#page_4',  '#page_5']; 
var allPages = '.page-container';

function show(prev, next) {
  $(prev).removeClass('show');
  $(next).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.page-container {
   transition: opacity 1s, width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out; 
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}

.show {
   transition: opacity 2s linear; 
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   opacity: 1;
}

.page-container.one {
  background: green;
}
.page-container.two {
  background: red;
}
.page-container.three {
  background: yellow;
}
.page-container.four {
  background: olive;
}
.page-container.five {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page_1" class="page-container one show" onClick="show(pages[0], pages[1])">1</div>
<div id="page_2" class="page-container two" onClick="show(pages[1], pages[2])">2</div>
<div id="page_3" class="page-container three" onClick="show(pages[2], pages[3])">3</div>
<div id="page_4" class="page-container four" onClick="show(pages[3], pages[4])">4</div>
<div id="page_5" class="page-container five" onClick="show(pages[4], pages[0])">5</div>
```

Анимированы так же with и height

transition: opacity 1s, width 1s ease-out, height 1s ease-out;

> **ease-out** Анимация начинается быстро, к концу замедляется

За счет того что width и height изменяются по заданной функции ease-out получается такой эффект.